# Concat two dataframe such that the new dataframe value appear as {cell1:cell2}

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe say

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3],
                  "col2": [4, 5, 6],
                  "col3":[7, 8, 9]})
```

and another dataframe say df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"colA": [10, 20, 30],
                  "colB": [40, 50, 60],
                  "colC":[70, 80, 90]})
```

I need to combine these two dataframe such that they form a dictionary like

```
col1     col2    col3
{1:10}  {2:20}  {3:30}
{4:40}  {5:50}  {6:60}
{7:70}  {8:80}  {9:90}
```

Now obviously this can be done using loops and apply function but I was looking for a more one liner or vector approach to do this because I have very large number of columns and rows and thus this needs to be optimized.

Comment: It is hard for vector approach due to the result is cell type object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that is similar to Chris'

```
(pd.concat([df1,df2.set_axis(df1.columns,axis=1)])
 .groupby(level=0)
 .agg(lambda x: dict([tuple(x)])))
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2     col3
0  {1: 10}  {4: 40}  {7: 70}
1  {2: 20}  {5: 50}  {8: 80}
2  {3: 30}  {6: 60}  {9: 90}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's ugly, but I believe it works for what you need.

The premise is to make sure all the column names are identical between the two dataframes, then stack them on top of each other using `concat`.  Then group by the index and convert each pair of values to a dict.  We are using a dict comprehension so it'll work for any number of columns.

This will end up inverting your df, so we can transpose, reset index, and then add prefix.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": [1, 2, 3],
                  "col2": [4, 5, 6],
                  "col3":[7, 8, 9]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"colA": [10, 20, 30],
                  "colB": [40, 50, 60],
                  "colC":[70, 80, 90]})

df2.columns = df1.columns

(
    pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0)
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg({col:lambda x:dict([list(x)]) for col in df1})
    .T
    .reset_index(drop=True)
    .add_prefix('col')
)
```

Output

```
      col0     col1     col2
0  {1: 10}  {2: 20}  {3: 30}
1  {4: 40}  {5: 50}  {6: 60}
2  {7: 70}  {8: 80}  {9: 90}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation as well

Comment: Will wait for some more answers meanwhile, if I don't get any better solution, will accept it in 12hrs

Comment: I couldn't think of a better way to do it without transposing.  Will be interesting of there is an approach that can avoid it!

Answer (score 1):

- Convert them to single value tuples.
- Add the tuples together.
- Convert the tuples to dictionaries.

```
df1 = ((df1.applymap(lambda x: (x,)) +
  df2.applymap(lambda x: (x,)).values) # have to use .values here so it doesn't try to match columns.
   .applymap(lambda x: dict((x,))))
print(df1)
```

Output:

```
      col1     col2     col3
0  {1: 10}  {4: 40}  {7: 70}
1  {2: 20}  {5: 50}  {8: 80}
2  {3: 30}  {6: 60}  {9: 90}
```

---

```
num_cols = len(df1.columns)
df = df1.join(df2)
for i in range(num_cols):
    df1.iloc[:, i] = df.iloc[:, i::num_cols].apply(lambda x: {x[0]: x[1]}, axis=1)

print(df1)
# Same Output as above
```